# htacces file & PHP parsing issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, html-parsing

There is a problem with PHP parsing the html files on my site.

I've been using php in html files, together with the directive
     AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
in the .htaccess file, without any problem for 5 years.

Since a couple of days ago, suddenly it doesn't work anymore.
Only the .php files are parsed properly and the html files are not, anymore
(the actual php code is displayed instead of the result of the execution!)

I contacted the host service but they say they can't offer support.

I thought that for some reason the .htaccess file is not read anymore by the server,
but I tested it with a redirect directive and it worked.

Then I thought that they modified something in the php engine and beside the above mentioned directive I've tried each of the following directives:
     AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
     AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
     AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
     AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm
but no success.

So html file are not php parsed anymore, but I've noticed someting interesting about the index.html file:
if I access mydomain.com/index.html  the result is bad,
HOWEVER, if I access just mydomain.com then it displays properly !!
(And of course, there is no index.php file). That means the index.html file is actually parsed, in this case.
BUT, the situation stays the same even if the .htaccess file is deleted.

For this particular file (index.html), the behavior is the same in any of the subdirectories.

As the hosting service is not helpful with checking their server configuration settings, 
I wonder if there is anything I can try on my side, as I'm stuck with this.
And any hints would be welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: A hosting service that answers "we can't offer support"? Well...

Comment: Using html files to be parsed by php is a terribad idea. You just learned why.